# Use a variable as name to access nested elements of another array

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I do a each-loop for an array which I build in a helper:

```
Template.article.helpers({
    section: function() {
        return [
            {type: 'cars', sectionTitle: 'Cars'}, 
            {type: 'vegetables', sectionTitle: 'Vegetables'}
        ];
    },
});
```

The data for the articles comes from the router:

```
Router.route('/article/:_id', {
    name: 'article',
    data: function() {
        return {
            article: Articles.findOne({ _id: this.params._id })
        }
    }   
});
```

But now I want to access a subelement of `article` with the `type` of the helper. So in this example the each loop will be done two times: I first want to use `../article.cars` and then `../article.vegetable`. I hope you understand my problem. I want to get the name of the subelement by the helper type:

```
<template name="article">
    {{#each section}}
        <h1>{{this.sectionTitle}}</h1>

        <ul>
        {{#each ../article.type}} <!-- should get '../article.cars' and '../article.vegetable' -->
            <li>{{this.title}}</li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

I want to use the content of `type` as a variable name. If type is 'cars', then I want to use `../articles.cars'. Which would be something like`articles['cars']`which would result of`articles[type]`. But in meteor this writing is not possible. And`articles.type` is something different.

Comment: This looks like it is specific to your view engine. What view engine is this?

Comment: @baao I think I need something like obj[name], but in meteor (see tags) there are dot notation used. But article.type is looking for the field type. But I want to use the content of type as name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use another helper:

```
s: function(article) {
    return article[this.type];
}
```

And send a argument with your spacebar:

```
{{#each s ../article}}
```